# Two Off Canvas sidebar on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new and not really good with HTML, CSS, JS, and Bootstrap. But I have a great idea (I think so :P) but I don't know how to achieve it.

My idea is to make a page with two Off-Canvas Sidebars:

- `First` Sidebar is on the `left` side and is `opened` as default when the page is loaded.
- `Second` Sidebar is on the `right` side and is `hidden` as default when the page is loaded.
- There is a close button on the left Sidebar when this button is clicked, it will hide left Sidebar and show the right Sidebar.
- And there is another close button on the right Sidebar to close right Sidebar and open left Sidebar.

Can anyone please help me?

Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: do you have tried anything? HTML/CSS?

Comment: Hi @J4R, I search Google a lot but I don't know how to modify it like my ideal. Can you please help me?

Comment: You need to create a [mcve] of what you tried, this question is too broad and show no effort on your behalf

Comment: @AlonEitan thank you, I will try and create other post.

Comment: @LongPhạm As I understand, you have the idea to create a page using HTML, CSS & Bootstrap but you don't know how to do it for now? To be short, you should do it yourself, or pay money to ask someone do it for you, we simple can't do it :).

Comment: @HuyTran okay, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot ways and possibilities to create something like you wish.

One possible solution, could be something like this:

```js
 document.getElementById('sidebar-left').addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.classList.remove('open');
        document.getElementById('sidebar-right').classList.add('open');
});
    
document.getElementById('sidebar-right').addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.classList.remove('open');
        document.getElementById('sidebar-left').classList.add('open');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page {
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 400px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.sidebar.open {
  display: block;
}

.sidebar.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: orange;
}

.sidebar.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.close {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="left sidebar open" id="sidebar-left">
    <div class="close">close sidebar</div>
    Left Sidebar
  </div>

  <div class="right sidebar" id="sidebar-right">
    <div class="close">close sidebar</div>
    Right Sidebar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can modify it from here. Thank you so much, @J4R.